# How to use ValueResolver of Automapper that has object configuration but are accessed for collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

In my MappingProfile, I have defined a mapping:

```
CreateMap<srcObject,destObject>()
.ForMember(srcObject.someProperty, opt=>opt.MapFrom<ValueHelper>())
```

and ValueHelper is

```
public class ValueHelper:IValueResolver<srcObject,destObject,destMember>
    {
        public ValueHelper()
        {
            
        }

        public int Resolve(sourceObject source,destObject destination,destMember output, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            // some logic
            return someNumber;
        }  
    }
```

Now I call mapper for the collection of object from a method as follows:

```
_mapper.Map<List<destObject>>(srcObjectList) //where srcObjectList is of type List<srcObject>
```

We don't require configuring map for List (or collection) types because mapper automatically uses the configuration that is done for the actual types (instead of their collections). So this mapper call works very well in normal cases; i.e. even after configuring the maps for `srcObject` and `destObject`, the mapping successfully happens for `List<srcObject>` and `List<destObject>`. But in above particular case, in the `ValueHelper` class, it doesn't have an overload for configuring logic for list (collection) types.

**What I tried?**

I tried creating a configuration for List types. But then, it throws the following error: "custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type"

```
CreateMap<List<srcObject>, List<destObject>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.Map<ValueHelper>());
```

and changed ValueHelper

```
public List<destObject> Resolve(sourceObject source,destObject destination,destMember output, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            // some logic
            return listOfDestObject;
        }
```

How to setup value resolvers in mapper whose mapper is configured for primitive/normal types (`srcObject`,`destObject`) in profile but from code is called for their collections (`List<srcObject>`,`List<destObject>`)?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using `ConvertUsing` and changing the `valueresolver` to `typeconverter`.

```
CreateMap<srcObject,destObject>();

CreateMap<List<srcObject>, List<destObject>()
                .ConvertUsing<ValueHelper>();
```

and ValueHelper

```
public class ValueHelper:ITypeConverter<List<srcObject>,List<destObject>>
    {
        public ValueHelper()
        {
            
        }

        public List<destObject> Resolve(List<sourceObject> source,List<destObject> destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
             foreach(var src in source)
                  destination.Add(context.Mapper.Map<destObject>(src))
            // some logic
            return destination;
        }  
    }
```